# Area between curve $x^n$ and other lines

Tags: integration

> Find the area between the curve $y = |x^n|$, where $n$ is a positive constant, the line defined by $y=-2$, and the lines defined by $|x| = 2$.

I have answered this question, but I don't know if my answer is correct, so that's why I'm posting it here.

We want $\displaystyle \int_{-2}^{2} (y = |x^n| -2)$

$$ [\space |\dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}| -2x ]_{-2}^{2}$$

Evaluate it and get $$ | \dfrac{2^{n+1}}{n+1} | - | \dfrac{-2^{n+1}}{n+1} | + 8$$

I believe the first 2 cancel out because of the absolutes, so $8$ is the answer.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The final answer cannot be independent of $n$ - it is clearly different when $n=1$ and $n=2$. You are making a mistake integrating $|x|$  :

Since the function is even, you get
$$
A = 2\int_0^2 (x^n - 2)dx = 2\left [ \frac{2^{n+1}}{n+1} -4 \right ]
$$

Comment: But why can't we just take $-2, 2$? Why do we have to take $2[0,2]$?

Comment: You need to differentiate between intervals where $x>0$ and $x<0$. The integral of $|x|$ is not $|x^2|/2$.